# ArangoDb: Is it possible to determine the direction of the current path?

Tags: graph, arangodb, aql

I was woundering if it is possbile to detemine the direction (OUTBOUND/INBOUND) of the current path? in case of using the ANY direction?

Something like this:

```
LET outboundPaths = (
    FOR v, e, p IN 1..depth ANY startNode GRAPH @graphName
        //if (p.Direction == "OUTBOUND") 
        //rest of code
        //if (p.Direction == "INBOUND") 
        //rest of code
)
```

`p.Direction` - There isn't a Direction property.

In order to support "ANY" this is what I've came up with:

```
LET direction = @direction // "OUTBOUND", "INBOUND", or "ANY"

LET outboundPaths = (direction == "OUTBOUND" OR direction == "ANY") ? (
    FOR v, e, p IN 1..depth OUTBOUND startNode GRAPH @graphName
        //rest of code
) : []

LET inboundPaths = (direction == "INBOUND" OR direction == "ANY") ? (
    FOR v, e, p IN 1..depth INBOUND startNode GRAPH @graphName
        //rest of code
) : []

LET allPaths = UNION(outboundPaths, inboundPaths)
```

The problems with my code is 1. double traverse 2. extra union step